# i can't connect to my server that i managed team network from public

Tags: networking, ethernet

i just managed team network on 2 devices with one ip. it's works on local but not from public i can ping and also ssh in local. i need to make this able to connect from public network.

```
[root@localhost ~]# nmcli con show lateam0
connection.id:                          lateam0
connection.uuid:                        12580848-9c9f-47df-86c4-8fb83e306c22
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        team
connection.interface-name:              lateam0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1648295449
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               8.8.8.8
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         202.131.4.61/27
ipv4.gateway:                           202.131.4.33
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
team.config:                            {"runner": {"name": "activebackup"}}
team.notify-peers-count:                -1 (unset)
team.notify-peers-interval:             -1 (unset)
team.mcast-rejoin-count:                -1 (unset)
team.mcast-rejoin-interval:             -1 (unset)
team.runner:                            activebackup
team.runner-hwaddr-policy:              --
team.runner-tx-hash:                    --
team.runner-tx-balancer:                --
team.runner-tx-balancer-interval:       -1 (unset)
team.runner-active:                     yes
team.runner-fast-rate:                  no
team.runner-sys-prio:                   -1 (unset)
team.runner-min-ports:                  -1 (unset)
team.runner-agg-select-policy:          --
team.link-watchers:                     --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           lateam0
GENERAL.UUID:                           12580848-9c9f-47df-86c4-8fb83e306c22
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        lateam0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       lateam0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         202.131.4.61/27
IP4.GATEWAY:                            202.131.4.33
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 202.131.4.32/27, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 350
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 202.131.4.33, mt = 350
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5cbf:b6ac:45c3:6054/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 350
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: okay, edited thanks for advise :D

Comment: Are you sure you are forwarding packets to `202.131.4.61`?

Comment: not sure, but i can ping and also ssh in local i am i have 3 interfaces 2 interfaces are managed as a team and named lateam0, 202.131.4.61